Toggle Desktops Vertically in KDE Plasma 5.27
I just upgraded to KDE 5.27.11 and it appears one my most used custom shortcuts cannot be done anymore.
I used to have Ctrl+Alt+Left and Ctrl+Alt+Right toggle between virtual desktops vertically (so I don't have to remember whether I want to go up or down), but now it seems that I need to set one to up and one to down, and going up/down when I'm already on the top/bottom does nothing.
Is there a way to have this work like it used to? IE: if I hit go up when on the top desktop, it advances to the bottom one.

Found it.
System Settings > Workspace Behavior > Virtual Desktops > toggle on "Navigation wraps around"
